# Function prints entirely

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Extremely new to AngularJs and trying to figure out why my function prints out entirely as follows.

```
Hello function () { return (this.sal) * 12; }
```

Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var app=angular.module("sample",[]);
    app.controller("emp",function($scope){
      $scope.Name="Jag";
      $scope.sal="4500"
      $scope.getAnnualSal = function()
      {
         return (this.sal) * 12;
      }
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="sample">
<div ng-controller="emp">
  Hello {{getAnnualSal}}
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is evaluating `getAnnualSal` as a property in the scope. If you want to execute it as a function in the scope, add `()`

```
{{getAnnualSal()}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it's a function not a variable:

```
Hello {{getAnnualSal()}}
```

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, you should be using as a function with `()`.

I wanted to also mention that your function should be using `$scope.sal` in Angular versus `this.sal`.

```
$scope.getAnnualSal = function () {
    return $scope.sal * 12;
}
```

And usage:

```
Hello {{getAnnualSal()}}
```